# Only show the first 10 characters in Google Spreadsheet cell followed by continuation character

Tags: google-sheets

I often have lots of data in spreadsheet cells but I don't necessarily want all the text to show in the cell as long as I can edit it in the formula bar.

So, for instance, I'd like to have the text "this text is a long sentence" in a cell but only display "this text is..." but if I click on the cell, the whole content displays in the formula bar so I can edit it.

I know that this relies on custom display formats but I can't find a way of making this work. There doesn't seem to be a placeholder for a single character, only the whole string (@).

EDIT

This is a link to the sheet ...

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Ahi1CsGAiD02tvAmKuQAKnNemyYdh6AUb1GcrwZCubI/edit#gid=2014979721

... this is a mock up of what I'd like to see in the cell.

[image]

Can anyone help?

Comment: share a copy of your sheet with example of desired output

Comment: I've added screenshot and link to the spreadsheet in the question :)

Comment: I don't think this is currently possible. I'd suggest you to request this functionality via `Help > Report a problem`.